# AEM - Need to add same user to multiple roles while creating project in AEM

Tags: aem, project, user-roles

While creating a project in AEM, we have the option of adding users for roles defined for the projects in the create project wizard.
The issue is I cannot add the same user to multiple roles. For e.g We have 2 reviewer roles and I want the same user to add to both the reviewer roles, I cannot do that.
We select the user, select the role as Role 1 and click Add.
Now we select the same user and select the role as Role 2, when we click Add, the previous entry that has user's role as Role 1 gets replaced by Role 2.

Is there a way we could add the same user to multiple roles ?

Comment: Did you try via the /useradmin console? A user can belong to many groups.